# How to remove duplicate values based on multiple columns

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a file tmp.log with fields like

```
description ID  valueA valueB valueC
xxx         x    1       1     1
yyy         y    3       100    23
zzz         z    0       0      0
aaa         a    4       4      4
```

I would like to remove data points which have same values across all 'value' columns

```
description ID  valueA valueB valueC
yyy         y    3       100    23
```

I am using

```
cat tmp.log | tail -n+2 | awk '!a[$3$4$5]++'
```

But it still prints the redundant values, why is this wrong and how to correct?

Comment: Wouldn't the last line have to be removed, too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove lines of which column 3, 4, 5 is the same:

```
awk '!($3==$4&&$4==$5)' data_file
```

Remove lines which has the same 3,4,5 columns with other line:

```
awk '!seen[$3,$4,$5]++' data_file
```

**update for n columns**

Remove lines of which column 3, 4, ...n is the same:

```
awk 'v=0;{for(i=4;i<=NF;i++) {if($i!=$3) {v=1; break;}}} v' data_file
```

- `v=0` reset v to 0 for every record
- `for(i=4;i<=NF;i++) {if($i!=$3) {v=1; break;}}` loop from 4th column to last one, set v to 1 and break if it's not the same as 3rd column
- `v` print if v is not 0.

Remove lines which has the same 3,4,...n columns with other line:

```
awk '(l=$0) && ($1=$2=""); !seen[$0]++ {print l}' data_file
```

- `(l=$0) && ($1=$2="")` backup original line, empty 1st and 2nd columns, rebuild `$0`. This expression always evaluated to false, so it won't print anything. Note that `&&` take precedence over `=`, that's why you need to `()` them;
- `!seen[$0]++ {print l}` usual `seen` trick, print original line if it's unseen before.

Answer (score -1):

Command: `awk '$3!=$4 && $4!=$5&& $5 !=$3 {print $0}' filename`

output

```
awk '$3!=$4 && $4!=$5&& $5 !=$3 {print $0}' filename
description ID  valueA valueB valueC
yyy         y    3       100    23
```

Comment: Could you explain how this is different from the other answers, and if it’s better, why it is better?

Comment: This is different from the other answers — it is wrong.  An input line ``James    Bond   0   0   7`` should be printed, because it does not have the same value in `valueA`, `valueB` and `valueC`.  The other answers print such a line; this one does not.